# Promise chain returned by ngbModal.open is skipped

Tags: angular, typescript

I am implementing data editing in a component. First I must check if one of data fields has been changed, and if so, a confirmation pop-up should open. If user confirms the change, the data will be updated.

From the `updateData()` method, I am calling the `isChangeConfirmed()` method which opens the pop-up and checks if the <kbd>Save</kbd> button was clicked on the pop-up. If so, it returns `true`. I expect the control to be returned to the `updateData()` method after calling the pop-up and checking the result. In the reality, the data is saved first, and then the pop-up window appears. What have I done wrong?

component.html

```
<button id="saveButton" type="button" (click)="updateData()" translate>BUTTON.SAVE</button>


<!-- POPUP -->

<ng-template #editModal let-modal>
  <button type="submit" id="modalConfirmButton" (click)="modal.close('save')" class="btn btn-primary" translate>BUTTON.CONFIRM</button>
  <button type="reset" id="modalCancelButton" (click)="modal.close('cancel')" class="btn btn-primary" translate>BUTTON.CANCEL</button>
</ng-template>
```

component.ts

```
updateData() {
  if (this.isChangeConfirmed()) {

    // Some code which updates data

  }
}

isChangeConfirmed(): boolean {
  if (this.oldValue != this.newValue) {
    this
      .ngbModal
      .open(this.editModal, { ariaLabelledBy: 'editModal' })
      .result
      .then((result) => {
        return result == "save";
      }, (reason) => {
        return false;
      });
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you open the modal, the part within `(result) => { /*asynchronous part*/ }` and `(reason) => { /*asynchronous part*/ }` runs asynchronously. It cannot be determined when these parts will run in comparison to the parts outside their context. Your `return false;` statement is within the asynchronous context, but your `return true;` is outside of it. So even if the `return false;` piece runs, you cannot know when it will happen, because you don't know when `this.ngbModal.open()` will produce a `result` or a `reason`. It seems like in your case not fast enough, and `return true;` is faster. But the point is that it's impossible to know.

This is all fine, but you can't put `return true;` inside `(result) => {... return true;}` either, because I suppose the compiler will complain that there is no return statement.

There are two ways to solve it that I can think of:

- You get rid of the separate function, put everything in one function, and put `// Some code which updates data` inside `(result) => {... /* Some code which updates data*/ }`
- Or if you really want to have a separate function, then what you need to do is not returning a `boolean`, but return an `Observable`, and subscribe to that `Observable` in `updateData()`. Look it up how you can pipe the two answers, `(result)` and `(reason)` into one single `Observable`, how to join them, create an `Observable` out of this, and return that.

If you go with the second option, I suggest you look at RxJS Operators (https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators). Also, reading articles on reactive programming can be useful.